# Rails reference a model with a non integer primary key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-migrations

I have a table whose migration is this:

```
class CreateClient < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :clients, :primary_key => :tag do |t|
      t.string :name
    end
    change_column :clients, :tag, :string, limit: 4
  end
end
```

so the primary key as you can see is that tag field which is a varchar(4), now I need to reference that field from another table. 
I tried in the migration to create the reference in this way:

```
t.references :client, index: true
```

but the resulting table has a field called client_id which is int, should I pass any parameter to the references method so that it will create the field as varchar?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Use `:id => false` to not generate `client_id` column.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you can use `execute` to force rails into setting the primary key in the way you want:

```
class CreateClient < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :clients, :id => false do |t|
      t.string :name
    end
execute "ALTER TABLE clients ADD PRIMARY KEY (name);"
```

And then set do `set_primary_key :name` in your Client model

Comment: He has set the primary key the way he wanted, he only want to use that primary key as a reference. This isn't answering the question